# Choose locale folder for template internationalization

Tags: python, django, templates, internationalization, django-i18n

I want to put my .po files in the single apps and not central in the main folder for my entire project. When I create the locale folders, and when I create the .po file inside the app, I will get the marked sentences for this app. But I have templates for that app in another folder in the projekt (A template folder for all app templates). I want to translate the .py files in the app, and I want to have the translations for the template of the app in the same .po file inside the app.

How can I get the template translations in the .po file of the app with a command.

Thats how I create the .po files inside the app:

```
python ../manage.py makemessages -l de
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a locale directory outside of your apps for those general templates and add:

```
LOCALE_PATHS=[BASE_DIR / "locale"]
```

to your config/settings.py